# How to equip skins to your weapon in Battlefield 1

Tags: battlefield-1

In Battlefield 1 you get skins when opening battlepacks. However the only page i know where i can equip these skins to a certain weapon is on this page https://www.battlefield.com/career.

The problem is that i get an 'Failed to equip item' when i try to equip the skin to my weapon.

Is this bugged and the only way to equip the skin to your weapon? Or are there some other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/how-to-change-weapon-skins-in-battlefield-1/) article.

> In Battlefield 1 you can earn and equip different weapon skins through Battlepacks. For whatever reason, you **can’t** just equip these skins at the Soldier Menu on the Main Menu.
>   
>   You will actually need to be in-game to switch your skin. Before you start a match you will have to pick a class. Remember that certain weapons are only open to certain classes so make sure the skin you want is actually on the class you are playing. Let’s say for instance you have a M 18 skin. Select the Assault Class and customize it with that weapon. When you have the weapon equipped click Triangle, or Y on the Xbox(click on "modify" for PC), and you will get some more options. Here you can switch a few things but at the bottom you can change the Visuals. This is where you can equip a new weapon skin.

You can also change skins on planes and tanks. 
If this wasnt what you asked for then I'll try to find more info.